# Mosquitto configuration log issues

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am struggling with a weird issue on my Mosquitto Broker that occurs after I enable logging using the configuration below.
I'm using MQTT explorer to monitor my broker; after changing the configuration I started experiencing problems, monitor constantly said this:

[image]

If I delete the line `log_dest file C:\Archivos de programa\mosquitto\mosquitto.log` it seems to be fixed.

I was adding the `log_dest` because I can not find the log file, please help me locate it.

Configuration File:

```
# Note that if the broker is running as a Windows service it will default to
# "log_dest none" and neither stdout nor stderr logging is available.
# Use "log_dest none" if you wish to disable logging.
#log_dest none 
log_dest topic 
log_dest syslog 
log_dest file C:\Archivos de programa\mosquitto\mosquitto.log
```

Comment: When you run mosquitto on the command line using the `-c` option to point to the config file does it show any errors? Do NOT run mosquitto as a windows service when trying to debug things.

Comment: Also you have spaces in the path, wrap it in quotes

Comment: what do you mean whit "-c" option? is that something from linux?  I am using windows, also how can I run mosquitto in anohter way? the only way that I know is as a windows service, using this command on cmd "net start mosquitto"

Comment: like this?----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- log_dest file C:\Archivos"de"programa\mosquitto\mosquitto.log

Comment: No to both questions. You run `mosquitto.exe -c c:\path\to\mosquitto.conf`. Running it as  a service means you don't get to see the output. And no, I meant quotes round the WHOLE path. (This is why sensible people don't do stuff like this on windows....)

Comment: When I start the aplication called "mosquitto.exe" it apppears a CLI Window but I can not write nothing there, am I in the right place to put that commamd that you told me?

Comment: Run it all from the command line.

Comment: I am triying to start mosquitto on cmd as administrator using "mosquitto.exe" but cmd says that it is not recognized as a internal or external comand or file, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: best guess you are not in the directory with the executable, but I'm done with this now.

Comment: I am so sorry for wasting your time sir, I am pretty new here and also sometimes I can misunderstand some concepts and stuff becuase english is not my first lenguage, after my apologies to you sir, this is the way that I found to setup and start mosquitto, https://youtu.be/72u6gIkeqUc , could you tell me if this way is wrong and please where to start it in a good way?